# Java listener call repaint

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, mouselistener

I have a JPanel where my (game)program draws something that is determined by a piece of code.
So far, so good.
I wrote a very basic listener that listens for the change to the background model of the program and is then supposed to tell the GUI to update, i.e. move a gamepiece.

All of this happens in a mouseListener triggered method.

I'm guessing that this is the problem, as clicking the mouse again in the JPanel updates the JPanel correctly and I can see the piece moved by the model.

Code for the JPanel:

```
@Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            update(g);
            
        }
```

Update calls a lot of AWT code that doesn't really matter for my issue, it just paints the game board.

(pseudo)Code from my controller, gets executed on mouse event by Mouse Listener:

```
public void human_and_cpu_move()
{
human_move(int x, int y, int x2, inty2)
cpu_make_move();
}
```

background model code

```
public void cpu_make_move()
{
do_something_cool;
tell_listener_something_cool_happened();
}
```

background Listener:

```
public class Background_listener()
{
Controller myController;
Background myBackground;
public Background_listener(Controller controller, Background background){
myController = controller;
myBackground = background;
}
public void tell_listener_something_cool_happened()
{
myController.get_JPanel.repaint();
}
}
```

What behavior do I see? the CPU moves are done only if I click the the JPanel again, they are not made on their own.
What do I want?
I want the CPU moves to be displayed as soon as they are done.
Thanks in advance for any help, I couldn't find a similar question.

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mre] that we can copy into our IDE, compile, and test.  Otherwise, you didn't provide enough code for an answer.  Also, Java conventions have method names in camel case format.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc : Okay, will do next time. Managed to solve this one myself, I'd forgotten to update the String that the GUI builds its representation of the game board with after the computer made it's move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem: I forgot to tell the GUI to update the game board representation it held from the background model. Simple problem, simple solution.